# Integrating a Skyscanner widget with React

Tags: reactjs

I would like to include a Skyscanner Widget within my React application.

https://partners.skyscanner.net/affiliates/widgets-documentation/basic-and-location-widgets

```
<div data-skyscanner-widget="BasicWidget" data-locale="en-GB" data-params="colour:glen"></div>
<script src="https://widgets.skyscanner.net/widget-server/js/loader.js" async></script>
```

As the script is stored externally, how would I go about integrating this within my react application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to add this script tag to your `.hmtl` file:

```
<script src="https://widgets.skyscanner.net/widget-server/js/loader.js"></script>
```

Then you can try to use this Component:

```
class MyWidget extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {

    window.skyscanner.widgets.load();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        data-skyscanner-widget="FlightSearchWidget"
        data-locale="en-GB"
      />
    )
  }
}
```

It will work in production and development mode.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/62frLb8q/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to include the external script to RIA.

1. `load-script` library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-script). Which can help you to load script dynamically. You can create a special Component and load script after mounting:

```
class ScyScanner extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    loadScript('URL')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div data-skyscanner-widget="BasicWidget" data-locale="en-GB" data-params="colour:glen"></div>

    )
  }
}
```

2. The next way is to create a tag for `skyscanner-widget` manually in the `index.html` document if you use it and attach `external` script by adding `script` tag. It's simpler but less flexible.
3. Also, you can create a function-helper which loads external script dynamically as soon as it's called:

```
export function loadExternalScripts() {
  if (env === 'production') loadScript('URL')
}
```

— then, your script can perform the loading script according to the environment.

As you have a link to JS `loader` (`https://widgets.skyscanner.net/widget-server/js/loader.js`). That means you don't care about script versions.